# NullPointerException error with Card and Deck classes

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
import java.lang.*;

public class Card
{
   String face, suit;
   int value;


   public Card (String a, String b)
   {
      face = a;
      suit = b;
      faceValue(face);
   }

   public void faceValue(String abc)
   {
      if (abc.equals("Jack") || abc.equals("Queen") || abc.equals("King"))
      {
         value = 10;
      }
      else if (abc.equals("Ace"))
      {
         value = 11;
      }
      else
      {
          value = Integer.parseInt(abc);
      }
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      return face + " of " + suit + "\nValue of: " + value;
   }

   public int getValue()
   {
      return value;
   }

   public static void main(String [] args)
   {

      Deck deck = new Deck();
      deck.fillDeck();
      System.out.println(deck.toString());
   }
}
class Deck
{
   Card [] cards;
   String [] faces = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King",    "Ace"};
   int  counter = 0;
   String deckList;

   public Deck()
   {
      cards = new Card[52];
   }

   public void fillDeck()
   {
      for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i++)
      {
         cards[i] = new Card(faces[counter], "Hearts");
         counter++;
      }

     counter = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i >= 13 && i <= 25; i++)
      {
         cards[i] = new Card(faces[counter], "Diamonds");
         counter++;
      }

     counter = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i >= 26 && i <= 38; i++)
      {
         cards[i] = new Card(faces[counter], "Clubs");
     counter++;
      }

     counter = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i >= 39 && i <= 51; i++)
      {
         cards[i] = new Card(faces[counter], "Spades");
     counter++;
      }

   }

   public String toString()
   {
      for (int i = 0; i <= 51; i++)
      {
         deckList = cards[i].getValue() + " ";
      }
      return deckList;
   }

}
```

This is the error I am getting and I'm not sure what it is. There were also some issues with the parseInt() from before and maybe it has something to do with that? This class is designed to be used for a black jack game but I can't seem to get passes this error, any help is appreciated.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Deck.toString(Card.java:100)
    at Card.main(Card.java:47)
```

Comment: try to debug it with some runtime values using a debugger, u will automatically know from where exception is coming.

Comment: have a another look at the way ur for loop are initialized and used.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Deck is not getting initialised because `For loop` is not correct.

Your loop is like this inside filDeck method:

```
for (int i = 0; i >= 39 && i <= 51; i++)
      {
         cards[i] = new Card(faces[counter], "Spades");
     counter++;
      }
```

But this will never run as you intialise i=0. So the first value of i will not meet the condition `i >= 39 && i <= 51` and loop will break.

I would rather put this for loop as:

```
for (int i = 51; i >= 39; i--)
          {
             cards[i] = new Card(faces[counter], "Spades");
         counter++;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Each one of your for loops starts with i=0. you need to change it to the lowerbound of the conditional otherwise it the for loop wont get run.

ex:lets step through the last one

```
for(int i=0; i >=39 && i <=51; i++)
```

i = 0, >=39 && i <=51?  no, do not enter for loop

change it to:

```
(int i = 39; i >= 39 && i <= 51; i++)
```